# Using Solve in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, puzzle

To get acquainted with Mathematica's solving functions, I tried to work out a solution to a [MinuteMath problem](http://amc.maa.org/mathclub/5-0,problems/M-problems/M-web,ia/2000web/m00-23-ia.shtml):

> There is a list of seven numbers. The average of the first four numbers is 5, and the 
>   average of the last four numbers is 8. If the average of all seven numbers is 46/7, then 
>   what is the number common to both sets of four numbers?

Of course, this is an excercise that can be solved without computer, but how can I solve this using Mathematica? My first approach

```
X = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, 7}];
cond = {
  Mean[Part[X, 1 ;; 4]] == 5,  
  Mean[Part[X, 4 ;; 7]] == 8, 
  Mean[X] == 46/7
};
Solve[cond, Subscript[x, 4]]
```

returned no solution. My second approach

```
X = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, 7}];
rules = {Mean[Part[X, 1 ;; 4]] -> 5,  
   Mean[Part[X, 4 ;; 7]] -> 8, 
   Mean[X] -> 46/7
};
Solve[
  Mean[X] == Mean[Part[X, 1 ;; 4]] 
    + Mean[Part[X, 4 ;; 7]] 
    - Subscript[x, 4] /. rules, 
  Subscript[x, 4]
]
```

gives a wrong solution (45/7 instead 6). What did I wrong?

Comment: Ok, there is a problem with the second approach. It should read 7*Mean[X] == 
 4*Mean[Part[X, 1 ;; 4]] + 4*Mean[Part[X, 4 ;; 7]] - Subscript[x, 4], but this reduces to `True` when applying `rules`... Why is that?

Comment: Your second approach has 3 serious problems. **1st** the LHS of your rules are quite complicated and in less contrived cases (or if you simplify/expand your equations before applying the rules) they will fail to match anything. **2nd** your equations aren't actually true. Explicitly expand and look at each side and you'll see what's happened. **3rd** When adding equations together you lose information. You lose what the equation differences are. So reducing the problem to a single equation like you have done will never yield the full result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first piece of code that you give is fine. The only problem is there is no solution for x_4 alone. If you replace the last line by `Solve[cond]` then Mathmatica automagically chooses the free variables and you'll get the solution.

---

I think that a simple/trivial example would make this type problem clear:

```
In[1]:= Solve[x==1&&y==2,x]
        Solve[x==1&&y==2,{x,y}]
Out[1]= {}
Out[2]= {{x->1,y->2}}
```

The final output can also be obtained using `Solve[x==1&&y==2]`, where Mma guesses the free variables. **This behaviour differs from that of Mathematica 7.** In Mathematica 8 a new option for `Solve` (and related functions) called [`MaxExtraCondtions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html) was introduced. This allows Solve to give solutions that use the new [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) and is intended to make the behaviour of solve more consistent and predictable.
Here's how it works in this simple example:

```
In[3]:= Solve[x==1&&y==2, x, MaxExtraConditions->1]
Out[3]= {{x -> ConditionalExpression[1, y==2]}}
```

See the above linked to docs for more examples that show why this `Option` is useful. (Although maybe defaulting to `Automatic` instead of `0` would be a more pragmatic design choice for the new option...)

---

Finally, here's your first solution rewritten a little:

```
In[1]:= X=Array[Symbol["x"<>ToString[#]]&,{7}]
Out[1]= {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7}

In[2]:= cond=Mean[X[[1;;4]]]==5&&Mean[X[[4;;7]]]==8&&Mean[X]==46/7;

In[3]:= Solve[cond]
         x4/.%
Out[3]= {{x1->14-x2-x3,x4->6,x5->26-x6-x7}}
Out[4]= {6}
```

Comment: Simon, in Mma 7 `Solve[x == 1 && y == 2, x]` yields `{{x -> 1}}` ; has this changed in v8?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yeah - it looks like it has. I thought it was a little strange that `Solve[x == 1 && y == 2, x]` didn't work in Mma8. The behaviour seems a little counter intuitive. Maybe it's unintentional and we should point it out to WRI.

Comment: @Karsten: @Mr.Wizard: Got a reply from WRI. This was an intentional change in Mma8 that is meant to lead to more predictable behaviour for more complicated examples. There is a new `Option` for `Solve` called `MaxExtraConditions` that controls this behaviour and is defaulted to `0`. See the edit.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps more compact:

```
Reduce[Mean@Array[f, 4] == 5 && 
       Mean@Array[f, 4, 4] == 8 && 
       Mean@Array[f, 7] == 46/7]
(*
-> f[5] == 26 - f[6] - f[7] && 
   f[4] == 6 && 
   f[1] == 14 - f[2] - f[3]
*)
```

Although for clarity, I probably prefer:

```
Reduce[Sum[f@i, {i, 4}] == 20 && 
       Sum[f@i, {i, 4, 7}] == 32 && 
       Sum[f@i, {i, 7}] == 46]
```

**Edit**

Note that I am using function upvalues as vars and not list elements. I prefer this way because:

- You don't need to initialize the list
  (`Table[Subscript ...` in your
  example`)
- The resulting expressions are usually
  less cluttered (No `Part[ ;; ]`, etc)

Comment: You guys are quick!  How often do you check for new questions?

Comment: @Mr.W: Your comment is only a couple of minutes behind!

Comment: @Simon I was thinking "oh, a new question, let's see if I can answer it first" but no, two people before me.  Don't you guys do anything else?

Comment: @Mr. Well, I am also fond of image processing questions

Comment: @belisarius Is it possible to know how Mma's `Reduce` worked in the case of your solution? It seems like magic.

Comment: @David The only difference with the usual Reduce[ ] usage is that I haven't specified vars. I found that Reduce will try to guess every undefined symbol if you enter just equations, but I don't know if that is properly documented. Or perhaps I am missing some  other oddity in my solution?

Comment: @David: Solve will do the same thing when not supplied with the variables to solve for.